# Problem converting column with date info as object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've a column with birth dates as object, the problem is when I tried to convert it into datetime, because it displays always the next warning

time data '27126' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

```
         date
0        05/06/1980
1        31/07/1947
2        07/01/1963
3        26/03/1973
4        30/01/1991
5        12/12/1991
6        13/08/1987
7        10/01/1944
8        23/06/1965
9        08/10/1995
```

till now I've tried the next codes:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Try with `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non matched datetimes to missing values, here `NaT`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
```